# Python3: The puzzle of inner syntax for 'functools.partial'

Tags: python

In Python 3.x official documents, we could find the source code about `functools.partial`, below:

```
def partial(func, *args, **keywords):
    def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
        newkeywords = keywords.copy()
        newkeywords.update(fkeywords)
        return func(*args, *fargs, **newkeywords)
    newfunc.func = func
    newfunc.args = args
    newfunc.keywords = keywords
    return newfunc
```

However, I can't understand the syntax for below

```
newfunc.func = func
newfunc.args = args
newfunc.keywords = keywords
```

Where could see about these similar syntax? I am pretty puzzled. Because, I got a fatal error when I try the below code:

```
def func(A, B):
    def func_m(*fargs, **fkargs):
        print(D+C)
        print(fargs, fkargs)
    func_m.D = A
    func_m.C = B
    return func_m

f = func(1, 2)
f()
```

But i got a `NameError` that name 'D' is not defined after i call `f()`.

Save my time, please!
Thanks.

Comment: Not enitrely sure, but what is the purpose of `D` and `C`? Couldn't you use `A` and `B` directly inside `func_m` ?

Comment: The problem is not in the `=` lines, that’s just an assignment like any other. Notice how you’re introducing previously undefined variables `D` and `C`, while all of `partial`s names are previously defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `partial`'s code doesn't cause a `NameError` and yours does is:

The `args` and `keywords` that are used inside the `def newfunc` block are not the attributes set on `newfunc` outside that block, but rather the parameters of the same name that are passed to `partial` itself.

The attributes that are set on `newfunc` can be accessed by the caller to partial to see which args/kwargs are already set on that function, but if you remove them from `partial`'s logic it will still work just the same (try it :) )

Comment: awesome! i try it then it work very well, so that mean is i can not assign a variance like `D+C` outside that block via `function_name.xxxx`? my problem is it.

Comment: and i just want to understand, which situation i could correctly use these syntax, like `function_name.xxxx`, then still work perfectly.

Comment: i try to rename `newfunc.args = args` to `newfunc.var1 = args` then i will get same error namely 'NameError', so the `args` and `keywords` are both default keyword for functions attributes like `__name__` or `__code__`?

Answer (score 0):

Those lines are for storing attributes which are sometimes handy for inspection. They do not affect what happens when the body of `newfunc` runs. In your case you can just do this:

```py
def func(A, B):
    def func_m(*fargs, **fkargs):
        print(A+B)
        print(fargs, fkargs)
    return func_m

f = func(1, 2)
f()
```

Comment: what do you mean by they are sometimes handy for inspection?

Comment: yup, i know your code could work, but my problem is that i can't understand why the partial function could use the way like `functions.xxx = xxx` to assign value.

Comment: @ihades You’re just assigning an arbitrary value to an arbitrary attribute on an arbitrary object. It has absolutely no deeper meaning and has no direct functionality within that code snippet.